# Use a complex java map in a jquery function

Tags: java, jquery, jsp

In a .jsp page I have a complex `java` map, like this:

```
 Map<UserDefinedType, Map<String, Boolean>> allMaps= (Map)request.getAttribute("allMaps");
```

I need to use this map in a `jquery` function. Is there any way to achieve this?

The `jquery` function looks like this:

```
$('#selectMenuId').click(function(){
var val =$('#selectMenuId').val();
var allMaps= <%= allMaps%>
// Is there any way to access all the keys and values of this allMaps variable?
});
```

Comment: do you get anything here `var allMaps= <%= allMaps%>`? what is getting printed there?

Comment: Not like that. You need to convert it to JSON (before printing it out in the Java code). And it would probably be better to use Ajax to fetch the JSON than to spit it out hardcoded into the HTML of the page.